# html5boilplate + ant build script + coffee script

Tags: html5boilerplate

I've successfully configured a html5boilplate project with ant build script, but I want it to build coffee scripts as well, how can I configure the build script to build it?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an issue on the [ant build script project](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script), and hopefully someone would be able to create a task for it!